# why is the following Angular 1.6 code not filtering to lowercase this way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

this is my controller code

```
myApp.controller('MainController',['$scope','$filter',function($scope,$filter){

  $scope.handle = '';
  $scope.lowercasehandle = $filter('lowercase')($scope.handle);

}]);
```

and this is the html part

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">

  <div>
    <label for="">What is your twitter handle?</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="handle">
  </div>
    <h3>www.twitter.com/{{lowercasehandle}}</h3>

</div>
```

but the same code works when I make lowercasehandle a function returning the lowercase version of handle. The below example works just fine when called in the html by invoking the function lowercasehandle() in the h3.

```
myApp.controller('MainController',['$scope','$filter',function($scope,$filter){

$scope.handle = '';
$scope.lowercasehandle = function() {
  return $filter('lowercase')($scope.handle);
};

}]);
```

So why can't I directly update the value of lowercasehandle in the first case. Why do I need to use a function here? Whatever changes I make in the controller are supposed to show in the view right? So then why I am unable to achieve what I want using the first method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case,

```
$scope.lowercasehandle = $filter('lowercase')($scope.handle);
```

won't be called when `$scope.handle` is updated by the user and is assigned only once as. Making it into a function works as it is called on every digest cycle, which then uses the updated value of `$scope.handle`.

Answer (score 0):

You define handle as an empty string and call the filter on the empty string thereafter. So the value can't change any more and will stay an empty string.

In your second example with the function, the function lowercases the string at the time it probably holds a string other than an empty string, so it can actually lowercase something.

Note that you can use the filter in your html too, in this situation it might be more suitable

```
<h3>www.twitter.com/{{lowercasehandle | lowercase}}</h3>
```

Conclusion:

The first try is a one time assignment, while the second one assigns every time things change.

Comment: But when I input something on the html page, it will change the value of $scope.handle too at the same time, and that in turn should change the value of lowercasehandle which should then render on the page as the updated value?

Comment: It will call the function again then. But maybe just stick with the html version of the filter, might be easier @Ravy

Answer (score 0):

Because in first version you are calling filter only once and with '' string as the argument.
but if you make it a function and call it every time then it will return proper result everytime.

Comment: according to the two way data binding what I update in the html input will be updated in the controller function right ? So won't the first code update everytime an user puts in some data in input field? If it does, shouldn't the filter  be applied again and again instead of just once?

Comment: for that you can use watch in angular for watching any variable change